# No Facebook login on app?

Tags: support, android-app, login

I used the SE Android app in the past and I normally log into Stack Exchange through Facebook. But on the app, I don't have a FB login button.

How do I login using my FB login ID like I do on the website?

Comment: Should I feature request this?